# Laravel Socialite: Legacy People API has not been used in project

Tags: laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite, google-plus-signin

I have used Laravel 5.4 with socialite 3.0 for social login on my web application. But nowadays I got an error **Legacy People API has not been used in project xxx**. Then I have made some changes in a core file of socialite package.
/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/GoogleProvider.php
Line 61: Replace https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me? by https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?

And update mapUserToObject function with below code:

```
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    $user['id'] = Arr::get($user, 'sub');
    $user['verified_email'] = Arr::get($user, 'email_verified');
    $user['link'] = Arr::get($user, 'profile');

    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => Arr::get($user, 'sub'),
        'nickname' => Arr::get($user, 'nickname'),
        'name' => Arr::get($user, 'name'),
        'email' => Arr::get($user, 'email'),
        'avatar' => $avatarUrl = Arr::get($user, 'picture'),
        'avatar_original' => $avatarUrl,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Alright? Are you facing any issue or getting any error?

Comment: Yes, I was faced but resolved now.

Comment: Hey! I face the same error (Legacy People API has not been used in project) from the beginning of the week... Everything worked properly for few months. 

Have you found any solution to the issue?

For now, I had to create a new project to fix that :|

Comment: @Axel186 Just follow the above steps and the issue gets fixed in your existing project also. Please drop a message here if still not fixed.

Comment: @VineetChauhan , can you please let me know which steps to follow for fixing this issue ?

Comment: Update socialite package to [3.3.0](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/releases/tag/v3.3.0)

Answer (score 7):

This Solution does work. Fixed my issue.

Thanks a lot.

Here is the whole file if anybody is having this issue. Just change GoogleProvider class located in:
./vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/GoogleProvider.php with this:

```
class GoogleProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface{

protected $scopeSeparator = ' ';

/**
 * The scopes being requested.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $scopes = [
    'openid',
    'profile',
    'email',
];

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getAuthUrl($state)
{
    return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', $state);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getTokenUrl()
{
    return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
}

/**
 * Get the POST fields for the token request.
 *
 * @param  string  $code
 * @return array
 */
protected function getTokenFields($code)
{
    return array_add(
        parent::getTokenFields($code), 'grant_type', 'authorization_code'
    );
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getUserByToken($token)
{
    //fixing legacy google+ api
    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?', [
        'query' => [
            'prettyPrint' => 'false',
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        ],
    ]);
    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    //fixing legacy google+ api
    $user['id'] = Arr::get($user, 'sub');
    $user['verified_email'] = Arr::get($user, 'email_verified');
    $user['link'] = Arr::get($user, 'profile');

    $avatarUrl = Arr::get($user, 'image.url');
    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => Arr::get($user, 'sub'),
        'nickname' => Arr::get($user, 'nickname'),
        'name' => Arr::get($user, 'name'),
        'email' => Arr::get($user, 'email'),
        'avatar' => $avatarUrl = Arr::get($user, 'picture'),
        'avatar_original' => $avatarUrl,
    ]);

}
```

}

Comment: thanks bro, it works for me..
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me? url with https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?

Comment: Update socialite package to [3.3.0](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/releases/tag/v3.3.0)

Comment: Been trying to figure this out and came across this and now all is well. On production side there wasn't a problem, but seems google only allows the legacy api endpoint if your app hit that legacy endpoint within 6 months. Since I took a break from developing my site, upon returning I had this problem with legacy!

Comment: @Brian If you already had the depreciated API working google will allow the API call but if your app hasn't been calling the API in the past they will want you to use the new call

Answer (score 3):

Replace

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?` url with 
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?`

Google has update the API Endpoint & it recommend to use this `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?` endpoint to get the user details.

https://developers.google.com/people/legacy

Comment: Update socialite package to [3.3.0](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/releases/tag/v3.3.0)

Comment: @EmptyBrain It's a production server. I don't want to change anything to avoid any complications. For now, this is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also have Laravel 5.4 and in my case helped upgrade `laravel/socialite` from 3.0.* to 3.4.

I set this setting in composer: `"laravel/socialite": "~3.0"` and ran `composer update`.
Don't forget to clear cache: `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that it says `legacy people api`, this often means you are trying to use one of the old [Google+](https://support.google.com/googlecurrents/answer/9217723?hl=en) scopes.

A lot of the profile related endpoints that where once part of the google+ api were moved to the [People api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest) after the shutdown of [Google+](https://support.google.com/googlecurrents/answer/9217723?hl=en) .

As you can see by the endpoint you are calling you are trying to use the old google+ endpoint which was shutdown years ago.

> googleapis.com/plus/v1

You should be using [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

The correct endpoint would be.

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}
```