# Laravel Socialite Providers GOOGLE ERROR Legacy People API has not been used in project

Tags: laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I have installed Socialite and Social Providers for Laravel. It's working with multiple other auth providers but I'm getting this problem with GOOGLE:

> Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Legacy People API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXXXX before or it

I have tried the fix suggested here [Laravel Socialite: Legacy People API has not been used in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706390/laravel-socialite-legacy-people-api-has-not-been-used-in-project) but not had success.

I have tried Adding the Google+ API in google console but that didn't work either, the error still occurred.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you've got an outdated version of Socialite. Google+ was shut down a while back; the newer versions of Socialite use a different API.

Comment: @ceejayoz BOOM!!! :) You got it almost right - I had both socialiteproviders/google and socialite installed - I removed the socialiteproviders/google version and now it works. So it's obviously a problem with socialiteproviders/google package. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You're most welcome, glad you could get it sorted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I had both socialite AND socialiteproviders/google installed and I removed the socialiteproviders/google package and now it works perfectly. So it's obviously a problem in the socialiteproviders/google package at this time.

```
composer remove socialiteproviders/google
composer update
```